# property 'baseurl' is declared but never used ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

recently I have updated my ionic project, but now I see a warning like this: Property 'BaseURL' is declared but never used.
and my app not working 
this is the declaration in the ts file  `@Inject('BaseURL') private BaseURL)` 
and i use it in the html to import some photos from a server

```
<img src="{{BaseURL+dish.image}}" />
```

Comment: Did you try removing quotes("")?

Comment: no without the quotes will not working because it's an address

Comment: No this is not true what you are passing doesn't seems like an address it is more of a Variable in which somewhere the address is stored.

Comment: If you will pass variable in quotes it will be used as a string and will not work accordingly.

Comment: look it will suppose to be (http://localhost:3000/)=string this is baseURL and the dish image= (images/x.png)also a string you figure it out in quotes will be string or address i know the problem where is in the updates in need to declare http to HttpClient not to http or use Safari